# Can't figure out why soup.find_all() returns an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a novice in Python and am practicing web scraping by using BeautifulSoup.

I've checked some similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858625/why-is-beautifulsoups-findall-returning-an-empty-list-when-i-search-by-class), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839937/beautiful-soup-returns-empty-list), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387710/soup-findall-returning-empty-list). However, I'm still get stuck in my problem.

Here is my codes:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_recorded_music_markets").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tbody = soup.find_all('table',{"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
```

First, I don't think the web page I'm looking for contains java script that was mentioned in similar questions. I intend to extract the data in those tables, but when I executed print(tbody), I found it was an empty list. Can someone have a look and give me some hints?

Thank you.

Comment: The ```jquery-tablesorter``` class looks like it is added by javascript. Omit that from the ```class``` parameter.

Comment: I see, sorry for my carelessness. By the way, is it roughly correct that javascript has a class started with "j"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove the jquery-tablesorter part. It is dynamically applied after the page loads, so if you include it, it doesn't work.

This should work:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_recorded_music_markets").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tbody = soup.find('table', {"class": "wikitable plainrowheaders sortable"})
print(tbody)
```

Comment: I got it. I removed the javascript part and that worked. Thank you!

Comment: If this helped you, can you please mark the answer as solved? Thank you